# ifelse statement in R to assign values to a new column

Tags: if-statement

I am very new to R so apologies if this is a simple question. I am currently in the process of creating new columns in my data and I would like to know how to assign a value of 1 or 0 based on the value in "ContourFix" but so that it will extend to the whole "Trial".

Here is my data:

```
Trial <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
ContourFix <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
Data <- cbind(Trial, ContourFix)
```

Here is what I would like my data to look like after the column has correctly been assigned:

```
Trial <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
ContourFix <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
TrialFix <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
FinalData <- cbind(Trial, ContourFix, TrialFix)
```

I have started with an ifelse statement to create my new column but I'm not sure how to assign a 1 for the rest of the trial:

```
Data$TrialFix <- with(Data,  
ifelse(ContourFix == "1", "1", "0")
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work;

```
Trial <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
ContourFix <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)

trial.ends <- c(which(diff(Trial)==1),length(Trial))
one.starts <- which(ContourFix ==1)

TrialFix <- rep(0,length(Trial))
for (i in 1:length(one.starts)){
   TrialFix[one.starts[i]:trial.ends[i]] <- 1
}
```

It's a bit hacky but should serve your purposes. It requires that every set of trials has at least one corresponding value for ContourFix and that your data is grouped as in the example.

Comment: Thank you, I possibly need to add in some kind of nested while loop to make the code work properly. For example: `ifelse(Data$ContourFix==1, '1' while(Trial=='previousrow'), '0')` I'm not entirely sure how to refer to the previous row in the code though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the desired relationship between TrialFix, Trial and ContourFix? Generally in R you should try to avoid looping and use indexing instead. That said for little problems I don't personally see a problem.

Comment: Essentially, when there is a 1 listed in the ContourFix column I would like the rest of that Trial to be assigned a 1. Likewise, when there is a 0 in ContourFix I would like the rest of that Trial to be assigned a 0. I was planning to do this in a new column called TrialFix.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I've been working on this for days with little progress but this script works perfectly!

Comment: Pleasure. You can mark the question answered if you're happy with the solution.